# How to make Non-overlapping UVs in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I m having trouble making my UV unwrap. When I select a vertice in the UV image editor more than one vertice is selected. is it the behavior or overlapping in my UV unwrap.

Comment: Could you specify a little bit more about *what you are going to create? What object? Why non-overlapping UVs? Which texture you are going to use?* Use [edit] to add details for it. And adding some picture can help people understand your question more.

Comment: If "keep uv and edit mode mesh selection in sync" is enabled (little cube with two orange dots at it's corners) then it is normal, because one vertex of the mesh can be multiple verts of the UV. For example if you have a rectangle made by two faces, then your mesh has 6 verts, but if you unwrap the faces individually they will have 8 verts. If you select a mutual vert from the middle of the mesh in the 3d view, it will select two verts in the UV editor. If you select one of them in the UV editor the result will be the same because the "sync".